# How to find $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})$ knowing $f(x) = \int_0^{g(x)}(1+t^3)^{-\frac12} \mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Argh I had a picture for this but don't have enough reputation for anything on here. I also don't understand how to insert the math notation in here.

If $f(x) = \int_0^{g(x)}(1+t^3)^{-\frac12} \mathrm{d}t$ where $g(x) = \int_0^{\cos x}(1+\sin (t^2))\mathrm{d}t$

I have to find $f'(\frac{\pi}{2}).$

I know it has something to do with substitution and I've tried integrating by parts and things like that too  but its not working out. I think there is something about the way that the questions been asked thats not helping anyway that is the first question.

There'll be more in the future I'm sure.

Comment: Put in the link to your picture. people here will take care. And, MathJaX is in place here. Enclose math between `$...$` and get guided by your intuition for what a symbol could be!

Comment: okay thanks for the advice. I'll play guesswork then. thanks henning for adding that in for me

Answer (score 1):

Note that $g(x) = \tilde{g}(y) = \int_0^y(1+\sin (t^2)) dt$, where $y=\cos(x)$. Moreover $f(x)=\tilde{f}(z) =\int_0^z(1+t^3)^{-1/2} dt$, where $z=\tilde{g}(y)$. So $f(x) = \tilde{f}(\tilde{g}(\cos(x))) = (\mathrm{notation}) = \tilde{f}(z(y(x)))$.

$$f' = \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d\tilde{f}(z(y(x)))}{dx} = \frac{d\tilde{f}}{dz} \cdot \frac{dz}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = (1 + z^3)^{-1/2} \cdot (1 + \sin(y^2)) \cdot (-\sin(x)) = (1 + 0^3)^{-1/2} \cdot (1+0) \cdot (-1) = -1$$
(note, that $z=g(x)=\tilde{g}(\cos(\pi/2))$ is an integral from $0$ to $0$, so $z=g(x)=0$).

Comment: I dont really understand where the method comes from. it seems to me that you have multiplied both the main equations and differentiated one of the limits but im not sure why or what rule you're using.

Comment: @TessaDangerBamkin: I rewrited that, is it clearer? I only use the chain rule and the fact that $d(\int_a^x f(t)dt)/dx = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

To make the work clear, put

$$h(x) =\int_0^{x}(1+t^3)^{-1/2} dt$$

$$m(x) = \int_0^{ x}(1+\sin (t^2)) dt$$

$$f(x) = \int_0^{g(x)}(1+t^3)^{-1/2} dt$$

$$g(x) = \int_0^{\cos x}(1+\sin (t^2)) dt$$

Then, we have that

$$F(x) = h \circ m \circ \cos(x)$$

Because of the chain rule we can solve this as follows:

$$F'(x) = h' \circ m \circ \cos(x) \cdot (m \circ \cos (x))'$$

$$F'(x) = h' \circ m \circ \cos(x) \cdot (m' \circ \cos (x)) \cdot (\cos (x))'$$

$$F'(x) = h' \circ m \circ \cos(x) \cdot (m' \circ \cos (x)) \cdot (-\sin(x))$$

So we now calculate our derivatives:

$$h'(x) = (1+x^3)^{-1/2}$$

$$m'(x) =1+\sin(x^2)$$

Now we're ready to plug in $\pi/2$. We have

$$-\sin (\pi/2)=-1$$

$$\cos (\pi/2) = 0 $$

so that

$$m'(0) = 1+\sin (0) = 1$$

So for the last one we have

$$h' \circ m(0) = h'(0) = 1$$

Finally, we get

$$F'(\pi/2) =  -1$$

Comment: okay think i get it now thanks :). I just need to work on understanding chain rule as a composite functio I guess and not in the leibniz notation that I was first taught.

Answer (score 1):

Write $H(t) $ for the first integrand.

If $f(x) = \int_0^{g(x)} H(t) \,dt$, then $f'(x) $ is defined as the limit of $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$, for $h\to 0$, so you have to compute
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h \int_{g(x)}^{g(x+h)} H(t)\,dt$$
The integral is  "difference between bounds" times "average value"; for continuous $H$ and small $h$, the average value is close to $H(g(x))$. So the integral 
is close to $(g(x+h)-g(x)) \cdot H(g(x))$.  The whole limit then comes out
to 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h (g(x+h)-g(x)) \cdot H(g(x))= g'(x)\cdot H(g(x)).$$
By the same reasoning, $g'(x) = (\cos x)'\cdot (1+\sin(\cos(x)^2))$.

Now plug in $x=\pi/2$, to get $g'(\pi/2) = (-1) \cdot (1+\sin(0)) = -1$.

Multiply this by $H(g(\pi/2))$.  $\cos(\pi/2)=0$, so $g(\pi/2) = 0$, and $H(g(\pi/2)) = H(0) = 1$.

So the result, if I have not miscalculated, is $-1$.